# Packaging AV streams from youtube into mpeg2 ts container?

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mp4, mpeg2-ts

I am trying to pull video streams from **Youtube** and repackage it into **MPEG2 TS** container.**Youtube** streams audio(.m4a) and video(.mp4) as separate streams and packages into mp4 container format at the client end.Are there any ffmpeg libraries or any tools which packages the individual streams into **MPEG2-TS** container?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ffmpeg has an `mpegts` option. First, you will need to merge your audio and video. There is a [great answer on Super User on how to merge audio and video](https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg) so I will not steal the answerer's rep by copying it.

Once you have your combined video, you can convert files to MPEG-TS like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -f mpegts -vcodec mpeg2video -sameq output.ts
```

<sub>([source](http://brontesaurusdev.blogspot.com/2010/06/transcode-to-mpeg2-ts-with-ffmpeg.html), I have no affiliation)</sub>